# 25-23 hour days on pandas dataframe datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by a datetimeindex. The frequency of the index is variable, but mostly is on a minute-based sampling.

Due to a database problem, dayligth saving time is not properly adressed on the indexing. So, on particular months/days I have duplicated values for the index. Is there a way (without using timezones) to handle 23-25 hour days on pandas so I can keep linear track of time over records?

Here is a small example of my problem:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-03-12 22:59:59', '2014-03-12 22:59:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:00:59', '2014-03-12 23:00:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:01:59', '2014-03-12 23:02:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:02:59', '2014-03-12 23:03:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:03:59', '2014-03-12 23:04:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:04:59', '2014-03-12 23:05:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:06:59', '2014-03-12 23:06:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:07:59', '2014-03-12 23:07:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:08:59', '2014-03-12 23:09:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:09:59', '2014-03-12 23:10:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:10:59', '2014-03-12 23:11:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:11:59', '2014-03-12 23:12:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:13:59', '2014-03-12 23:13:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:14:59', '2014-03-12 23:14:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:15:59', '2014-03-12 23:16:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:16:59', '2014-03-12 23:17:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:17:59', '2014-03-12 23:18:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:19:59', '2014-03-12 23:19:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:20:59', '2014-03-12 23:20:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:21:59', '2014-03-12 23:22:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:22:59', '2014-03-12 23:23:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:24:59', '2014-03-12 23:24:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:25:59', '2014-03-12 23:26:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:26:59', '2014-03-12 23:27:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:27:59', '2014-03-12 23:28:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:28:59', '2014-03-12 23:29:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:30:59', '2014-03-12 23:30:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:31:59', '2014-03-12 23:31:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:32:59', '2014-03-12 23:33:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:33:59', '2014-03-12 23:34:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:34:59', '2014-03-12 23:35:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:36:59', '2014-03-12 23:36:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:37:59', '2014-03-12 23:38:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:38:59', '2014-03-12 23:39:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:40:59', '2014-03-12 23:40:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:41:59', '2014-03-12 23:42:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:42:59', '2014-03-12 23:43:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:44:59', '2014-03-12 23:44:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:45:59', '2014-03-12 23:46:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:46:59', '2014-03-12 23:47:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:48:59', '2014-03-12 23:48:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:49:59', '2014-03-12 23:49:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:50:59', '2014-03-12 23:51:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:51:59', '2014-03-12 23:52:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:52:59', '2014-03-12 23:54:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:56:59', '2014-03-12 23:58:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:54:00', '2014-03-12 23:55:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:56:59', '2014-03-12 23:57:59',
           '2014-03-12 23:59:59'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Timestamp', freq=None)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Mi problem is that I need information regarding consecutive observations in time,because, as I said, the main problem with this is that the frequency of the observations is variable and at some point I will have to interpolate data. So I need to be able to determine the correct amount of time between consecutive observations. I dont know if the datetime indexing will help me somehow with this

Comment: How can you tell which duplicate timestamp belongs to a different day?

Comment: @wwii my best guess (and only) is that if there are two records on the same date, then the second must be for the 'next' hour. However if the time difference is negative things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that date index are not mutable so you can't have inplace operations modifying them, you'll have to write over it.

One solution could be to "unroll" the index to still have the same number of time steps but every other timestamp would be pushed forward/backward an hour.

I refer to your index in the OP as `index` :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

first_step = df.index[::2] # every second index

## shift everyone forward starting from the second value, grab every second value ##

second_step = df.index[1::2].shift(periods=1,freq='1H')

new_index = first_step.append(second_step)

df.index = new_index
```

I can't help but feel that it's weird, tell me if that helps.

Comment: your sugestion helps a little. But it assumes that every data is duplicated and that is not the case. If you look closely to the example, you will see that there are unique records and even there is a missmatch at the end. But you gave me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I think your best bet then is splitting the records with what I typed above or some version of it and then interpolate to have consistent values if a record is missing

Comment: Thank you i will do that